# Build proper json post sharepoint list comment

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

First get request:
[image]

Parse json and post request:
[image]

I can send comment text to other list, but how can built proper json body to send more data for example, author or date create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only available property you can pass when creating a comments and replies is `text`.

The comments endpoint does not support passing dates, user names or any other properties, unfortunately.

So, if you want to post comments for different people, you need to be logged in as these users.